# Redirect www to non-www heroku

Tags: heroku, redirect, dns, record

I have `mydomain.com.au` setup with a DNS provider. I have successfully pointed my DNS target through Heroku to my DNS provider. However, to do so, I had to use a `CNAME` record to do so. As such, the web app is now available at `www.mydomain.com.au`.

I am trying to redirect `www.mydomain.com.au` to `mydomain.com.au` instead. This seems to be quite challenging. As per this [Heroku Guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains), I need to use specific DNS providers that support `ALIAS` or `ANAME` records to do this. However, none of their DNS providers support domain transfer of `.com.au`

Does anyone have an alternative????

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloudflare DNS, where you can enable proxy and configure the website to redirect if the user visits `www.mydomain.com.au`.